# Unable to install node module from git repository in CirlcleCI

Tags: node.js, git, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

Following is the scenario

ParentNodeModule in a git repo which consumes ChildNodeModule from another get repo and refers it in package dependency as git+ssh://git@github.com/SomeOrg/ChildNodeModule.git#1.0.0.

Now problem is that ParentNodeModule as a circle ci setup which should run tests and lint checks but its not able to because in cirlce ci its no able to access git@github.com/SomeOrg/ChildNodeModule.git and showing following error

```
npm ERR! ERROR: Permission to SomeOrg/ChildNodeModule.git denied to deploy key
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
n
```

So how to solve it any clues would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Within `CircleCI`, you should grant access to the `SomeOrg/ChildNodeModule` project so that `CircleCI` can read that repository. `CircleCI` will automate this process by adding a `Deploy Key` to that repository.